# File Upload Control Get Returned Null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Whenever i am clicking on submit after uploading file, it gets returned null, i have used all the necessary conditions required for upload file but still getting the issue, i have seen all the answers in stack overflow , i have used enctype and name of file upload is also same as what i am passing controller

```
public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }


        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Officername,Designation,FileBeforeTour,FileAfterTour,FileBeforeTourName,FileAfterTourName")] FileDetails fileDetails)
        {
              if (ModelState.IsValid)
              {
                string uploadedfilename = Path.GetFileName(fileDetails.filebeforetourupload.FileName);
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(uploadedfilename))
                {


                    db.FileUpload.Add(fileDetails);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
              }

            return View(fileDetails);
        }
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace OnlineStationaryRegister.Models
{
    public class FileDetails
    {
        [Key]
        public int FileId { get; set; }
        public string Officername { get; set; }
        public string Designation { get; set; }
        public string FileBeforeTour { get; set; }
        public string FileAfterTour { get; set; }
        public string FileBeforeTourName { get; set; }
        public string FileAfterTourName { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public HttpPostedFileBase filebeforetourupload { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public HttpPostedFileBase fileaftertourupload { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```
@model OnlineStationaryRegister.Models.FileDetails

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm("Create","File",FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>FileDetails</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Officername, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Officername, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Officername, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Designation, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Designation, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Designation, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("File", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="file" name="filebeforetourupload" />
            </div>
        </div>

        @*<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FileAfterTour, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
               <input type="file" name="fileaftertourupload" />
            </div>
        </div>*@



        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your controllers method as,This will fix your issue

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(FileDetails fileDetails)
    {
          if (ModelState.IsValid)
          {
            string uploadedfilename = 
                 Path.GetFileName(fileDetails.filebeforetourupload.FileName);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(uploadedfilename))
            {
                db.FileUpload.Add(fileDetails);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
          }

        return View(fileDetails);
    }
```

Comment: @sunnykumar,you have not included  filebeforetourupload  in your binding and you are using it to get the filename.If its working for you do.UpVote the answer. Happy Coding !!

Comment: but the filebeforetour is not mapped directly with the database , i m using it just to get the filename

Comment: @sunnykumar,but you are using filebeforetourupload to get the filename from it.right?

Answer (score 0):

Okay then this is what you should do. Instead of putting the `HttpPostedFileBase` field as part of the model, remove it from there and do this

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Officername,Designation,FileBeforeTour,FileAfterTour,FileBeforeTourName,FileAfterTourName")] FileDetails fileDetails, HttpPostedFileBase myFile)
{

}
```

then you can manipulate if from there. Sometimes the browser does not properly include files inside the model.